mermaid diagram not render in github
I have an readme.md file in github with the following content
```mermaid
gitGraph
    commit
    commit
    branch develop
    checkout develop
    commit
    commit
    checkout main
    merge develop
    commit
    commit    
``` 

however i am getting the below error
Unable to render rich display
Diagram error not found.
For more information, see https://docs.github.com/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-diagrams#creating-mermaid-diagrams

It works for me.
